# Question about GNU make built-in function subst with secondary expansion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some question about GNU make with secondary expansion feature.

Here is my project structure ( just for example )

```
.
├── build
├── Makefile
└── src
    └── a.c
```

And here is my Makefile with secondary expansion enabled

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: $$(subst build,src,%.c)
        @echo $^
```

I type `make build/a.o`, GNU make complains:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/a.o'.  Stop.
```

Looks like make does not find prerequisites so it stop making.

For further debugging, I add `a.c` in `build` directory and re-type `make build/a.o`, GNU make output these

```
build/a.c
```

The output is weird since I expect the output will be `src/a.c` instead of `build/a.c`

It seems that the built-in text function `subst` does not work with secondary expansion.

Does someone know what is wrong with my Makefile?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `.SECONDEXPANSION` you will need to use `$$*` instead of `%` if you want to manipulate the prerequisites, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: $$(subst /build,/src,$$(@D))/$$*.c
        @echo Making $@ from $<
```

Output:

```
$ make -r OtherDirectory/build/foo.o SomeOtherDirectory/build/bar.o
Making OtherDirectory/build/foo.o from OtherDirectory/src/foo.c
Making SomeOtherDirectory/build/bar.o from SomeOtherDirectory/src/bar.c
```

Comment: Why does `$$*` is valid instead of `%` symbol, I can't distinguish the difference between these two directive.
Thank you~

Comment: I have another questions about how the prerequisites will be interpreted as `OtherDirectory/src/foo.c` instead of `OtherDirectory/src/OtherDirectory/build/foo.c` since `$$*` is `OtherDirectory/build/foo` and it is concatenated after `OtherDirectory/src` after string substitution.

Comment: Frankly speaking I have no idea. At rule evaluation level it tries to use stem of 'foo' not 'OtherDirectory/build/foo', which is why I added $$(@D) to get the directory. I think this construction is a very non-standard use and probably a corner case, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
build/%.o: src/%.c
    @echo $^
```

observe:

```
$ make build/a.o
src/a.c
```

second expansion in combination with pattern rule and files in a directory is a tough beast. i have not fully understood why your construct does not work. just that it does not work. will update post when i understand fully.

for more information:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Your explanation is excellent. By the way if the target name is in this form `OtherDirectory/build/a.o` and the expected prerequisite is in this form `OtherDirectory/src/a.c`, is it possible to use `patsubst` to do the substitution? Thank you!

Comment: The phases described here are not actually correct.  Secondary expansion happens when the target is to be built, after the automatic variables are assigned.  It's not the case that make goes through all the rules and resolves all secondary expansion before it starts trying to run recipes.

Comment: i read the manual again. you are right. my explanation is not completely correct. i will try to reword my explanation so it is more correct.

Comment: @lesmana do you have any thoughts about this problem ?
I think the problem is that subst can not find the a target to do the substitution since I typed `make -Rd build/a.o` and it told me that it can not find the `build/a.c`. But I really do not know thy it does not work.